# Terminal commands can not be found OSX

Tags: macos, osx-mavericks

A majority of terminal commands don't work, for example .

`ls
sudo
vi`

with the error `-bash: ls: command not found` my path is `echo $PATH
“/Users/username/usr/local/bin` I get the feeling that `“` should not be there but not sure how edit it.

What should the path be and how do I get the path to stay the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add more paths to your $PATH variable. Try running `whereis ls` and check where is the binary of the command.

You can add more paths  like this: `export PATH=$PATH:NEW_PATH`

Comment: Then run the following: `export PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin`

Comment: Yay, that worked - so how do I fix this so it works after a reboot?

Comment: click answer question below, state your answer

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar experience recently where a lot of my terminal commands were not being found despite being clearly saved in my bash_profile. After lengthy process of elimination I realised that the issue was caused when I tried to export a new path. The error that I had made was putting a space in the command. So I had to change

export SOMETHING = /path/to/something.apk to
export SOMETHING=/path/to/something.apk

So I would recommend you check all your path declarations to ensure you don't have any white spaces. Also don't forget to source your bash_profile or what ever type of command line shell you use.